# data.table: Using with=False and transforming function/summary function?

Tags: r, data.table, lapply, summarization, group-summaries

I want to summarise several variables in data.table, output in wide format, output possibly as a list per variable. Since several other approaches did not work, I tried to do an outer lapply, giving the names of the variables as character vectors. I wanted to pass these in, using with=FALSE.

```
carsx=as.data.table(cars)
lapply( list(speed="speed",dist= "dist"), #error object 'ansvals' not found
    function(x)  carsx[,list(mean(x), min(x), max(x) ), with=FALSE ] )
```

Since this does not work, I tried the more simple approach without lapply.

```
carsx[,list(mean("speed"), min("speed"), max("speed") ), with=FALSE ] #error object 'ansvals' not found
```

This does not work either. Is there any way to do something like this? Is this behaviour of 'with' wanted? (I am aware that `?data.table` mentions with only to select columns, but in my case it would be useful to be able to transform them as well)

> When with=FALSE, j is a vector of names or positions to select, similar to a data.frame. with=FALSE is often useful in data.table to select columns dynamically.

EDIT 
My aim is to get  a summary per group in wide format, for different variables. 
I tried to extend the following, which works only for one variable, for a list of variables.

```
carsx[,list(mean(speed), min(speed), max(speed) ) ,by=(dist>50)
```

Lamentably SO doesnt let me post my other question. There I described that I want an output similiar to:

```
lapply( list(speed="speed",dist= "dist"),
        function(x) do.call("as.data.frame", aggregate(cars[,x], list(class=cars$dist>50), FUN=summary) ) )
```

Expected Output would be something like:

```
$speed 
         V1       V2 V3
1: FALSE 12.96970  4 20
2:  TRUE 20.11765 14 25

$dist
         V1       V2 V3
1: FALSE 12.96970  4 20
2:  TRUE 20.11765 14 25
```

Comment: I want to get summary statistics in a wide format, possibly in a list per (grouped) variable. For that I tried the outer lapply, and therefore Svens' answer is also not the right one for me...

Comment: I group by (dist>50)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on Svens answer a combination of .SDcols, rbindlist, and outer and inner lapply did the trick. The inner lapply is necessary to access .SD.

```
lapply( list(speed="speed",dist= "dist"),
    function(x)  carsx[ , rbindlist(lapply(.SD, function(x) list(mean=mean(x), min=min(x), max=max(x)) )), 
                       .SDcols = x,by= (dist>50)] )
```

Result:

```
$speed
    dist     mean min max
1: FALSE 12.96970   4  20
2:  TRUE 20.11765  14  25

$dist
    dist     mean min max
1: FALSE 27.84848   2  50
2:  TRUE 72.35294  52 120
```

Answer (score 5):

You can specify the columns with the `.SDcols` parameter:

```
carsx[ , lapply(.SD, function(x) c(mean(x), min(x), max(x))), 
      .SDcols = c("speed", "dist")]
#    speed   dist
# 1:  15.4  42.98
# 2:   4.0   2.00
# 3:  25.0 120.00

carsx[ , lapply(.SD, function(x) c(mean(x), min(x), max(x))), 
      .SDcols = "speed"]
#    speed
# 1:  15.4
# 2:   4.0
# 3:  25.0
```